# 2 identities of Shanks from Apostol's Book

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions

I am trying exercises of Ch-14 partitions from Tom Apostol Introduction to ANT and unable to Solve (a) part of Question 5.

**5.** If $x\ne 1$ let $Q_0(x)=1$ and for $n\ge 1$ define
$$ Q_n(x) = \prod_{r=1}^n \frac{1-x^{2r}}{1-x^{2r-1}}. $$
(a) Derive the following finite identities of Shanks:
$$ \sum_{m=1}^{2n} x^{m(m-1)/2} = \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \frac
   {Q_n(x)}{Q_s(x)} x^{s(2n+1)}, $$
$$ \sum_{m=1}^{2n+1} x^{m(m-1)/2} = \sum_{s=0}^{n} \frac
   {Q_n(x)}{Q_s(x)} x^{s(2n+1)}. $$
(b) Use Shank's identities to deduce Gauss' triangular-number
theorem:
$$ \sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{m(m-1)/2} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty
   \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n-1}} \text{ for } |x|<1. $$

I have question in proof of (a) as I am unable to derive any of the identity. I tried by evaluating $Q_n(x) / Q_s(x) $ and if I multiply it by $ x^{s(2n+1) }$ I don't see anything to get LHS in (I).

So, kindly shed some light on how to prove it by proving any of the identity.

I shall be really thankful for your help.

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUJbT.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main theme:** We set  for $n\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
A_n(x)=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\frac{Q_n(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n+1)}\qquad\qquad
S_n(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{2n}x^{\frac{m(m-1)}{2}}\\
\end{align*}
and find a representation of $A_n(x)$ via $A_{n-1}(x)$ by also separating terms which are summands from $S_n(x)$.
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A_n(x)}&=A_{n-1}(x)+x^{(n-1)(2n-1)}+x^{n(2n-1)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=A_{n-1}(x)+S_{n}(x)-S_{n-1}(x)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We so derive by induction
\begin{align*}
A_n(x)-S_n(x)&=A_{n-1}(x)-S_{n-1}(x)=\cdots\\
&=A_{1}(x)-S_{1}(x)\\
&=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}-(1+x)=0
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

**Proof:** The derivation of (1) is elementary but technically tricky.

> We start with an algebraic identity. The following holds:
> \begin{align*}
> \left(1-x^{2n}\right)x^{s(2n+1)}&=\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)x^{s(2n-1)}+\left(1-x^{2s+1}\right)x^{(s+1)(2n-1)}\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad-\left(1-x^{2s}\right)x^{s(2n-1)}
> \end{align*}
>
> The identity (2) can be shown easily my multiplying out and comparing corresponding terms. The idea is to represent the left-hand side by an expression where $n$ is consequently replaced with $n-1$. This will be used as building block to obtain the sums in (1). Division of (2) by $1-x^{2n-1}$ gives
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n-1}}x^{s(2n+1)}&=x^{s(2n-1)}+\frac{1-x^{2s+1}}{1-x^{2n-1}}x^{(s+1)(2n-1)}\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad-\frac{1-x^{2s}}{1-x^{2n-1}}x^{s(2n-1)}
> \end{align*}
>
> Recalling $Q_n(x) = \prod_{r=1}^n \frac{1-x^{2r}}{1-x^{2r-1}}$ we have $$Q_n(x)=Q_{n-1}(x)\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^{2n-1}}$$ We obtain from (3) by expanding with $\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{Q_n{x)}}{Q_{s}(x)}x^{s(2n+1)}&=\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_{s}(x)}x^{s(2n-1)}
> +\underbrace{\frac{1-x^{2s+1}}{1-x^{2n-1}}\,\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{(s+1)(2n-1)}}_{\alpha_{s,n}(x)}\\
> &\qquad-\underbrace{\frac{1-x^{2s}}{1-x^{2n-1}}\,\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n-1)}}_{\beta_{s,n}(x)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

**Intermezzo**:

We obtain for $s=0,\ldots,n-2$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\beta_{s+1,n}(x)}&=\frac{1-x^{2s+2}}{1-x^{2n-1}}\,\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_{s+1}(x)}x^{(s+1)(2n-1)}\\
&=\frac{1-x^{2s+2}}{1-x^{2n-1}}\,\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}\,\frac{1-x^{2s+1}}{1-x^{2s+2}}x^{(s+1)(2n-1)}\\
&=\frac{1-x^{2s+1}}{1-x^{2n-1}}\,\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{(s+1)(2n-1)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\alpha_{s,n}(x)}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

We also have $\beta_{0,n}(x)=0$ and
\begin{align*}
\alpha_{n-1,n}(x)=\frac{1-x^{2n-1}}{1-x^{2n-1}}\,\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_{n-1}(x)}x^{n(2n-1)}=x^{n(2n-1)}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

> Summing (4) from $s=0$ to $n-1$ we obtain with (5) and (6)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A_n(x)}&=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\frac{Q_{n}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n+1)}\\
> &=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n-1)}+\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\alpha_{s,n}(x)-\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\beta_{s,n}(x)\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n-1)}+\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\alpha_{s,n}(x)-\sum_{s=0}^{n-2}\beta_{s+1,n}(x)\tag{8}\\
> &=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n-1)}+\alpha_{n-1,n}(x)\tag{9}\\
> &=\sum_{s=0}^{n-2}\frac{Q_{n-1}(x)}{Q_s(x)}x^{s(2n-1)}+x^{(n-1)(2n-1)}+x^{n(2n-1)}\tag{10}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=A_{n-1}(x)+S_{n}(x)-S_{n-1}(x)}
> \end{align*}
> which proves the claim. The other identity in (a) follows by adding the term with $s=n$ to both sides of the first identity.

*Comment:*

- In (7) we use the identity (4) and sum from $s=0$ to $s=n-1$. We set the lower index of the right-most sum to $s=1$ since $\beta_{0,n}(x)=0$.
- In (8) we shift the index of the right-most sum by one to start with $s=1$.
- In (9) we use the telescoping property $\alpha_{s,n}(x)-\beta_{s+1,n}(x)=0$ for $s=0,\ldots, n-2$.
- In (10) we separate the term with $s=n-1$ from the sum and use the identity (6).

**Note:** This proof was given by D. Shanks in *[Two Theorems of Gauss](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103039902)* in 1958.

Comment: @User: Many thanks for granting the bounty.